# How to save in a file in C

Tags: c, fopen

```
#include "Header.h"

void mostraTabuleiro(int lin, int col, int **m){
int i, j, l;
char k = 65;

for (l = 1; l <= col; l++){

    printf("\t%c", k);
    k++;

}
printf("\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= lin; i++){
        printf("%d", i);
        for (j = 1; j <= col; j++){
            if (i == lin && j == col)
                printf("\t[X]");                
            else
                printf("\t[*] ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and now i want to save the mostratabuleiro in a file and i started doing this

```
int GuardaFicheiro(char *nome_fich){

FILE *fnovo;
char *novo_fich = "estadosTabuleiro.txt";



fnovo = fopen(novo_fich, "wt");
if (fnovo == NULL){
    printf("Erro ao abrir o ficehiro de texto %s para escrita.\n", novo_fich);
    return;
}




//mostraTabuleiro(6, 8, Tabuleiro, fnovo);


fclose(fnovo);
}
```

if i put fprintf in the function mostraTabuleiro after that it doesn't appera anything and the file is blank.

Comment: Take a look at the example of the function [`fprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) !

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with `malloc` or `structure`.

Comment: Exactly what is the problem?

Comment: @AjeetShah yes, but only the board, the sentences that are shown before i don't need them.

Comment: @AjeetShah i put it now in the question.....

Comment: @AjeetShah okay i could change the code around and it kinda worked but it doesn't apper on the screen anymore and the file is empty.

Comment: @AjeetShah i saw it. thank you, i will test it now if it works i'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may please note that you should ask question on S.O. in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) style. You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

```
void mostraTabuleiro(int lin, int col, int **m, FILE *fnovo) {

    int i, j, k;

    for (k = 1; k <= col; k++){
        fprintf(fnovo, "\t%d", k);
    }

    fprintf(fnovo, "\n");
        for (i = 1; i <= lin; i++){
            fprintf(fnovo, "%d", i);
            for (j = 1; j <= col; j++){
                if (i == lin && j == col)
                   fprintf(fnovo, "\t[X]");
                else
                    fprintf(fnovo, "\t[*] ");
            }
        fprintf(fnovo, "\n");
        }
}
```

and

```
void GuardaFicheiro(int lines, int columns, int **m){
    FILE *fnovo;
    char *novo_fich = "estadosTabuleiro.txt";

    fnovo = fopen(novo_fich, "wt");
    if(fnovo == NULL){
        printf("error opening file %s for writing.\n", novo_fich);
        return;
    }
    // this will write to the file
    mostraTabuleiro(lines, columns, m, fnovo);

    // this will write on screen : stdout
    mostraTabuleiro(lines, columns, m, stdout);

    fclose(fnovo);
}
```

and

```
int iniciaJogo() {

    tabuleiro tab;
    int i, j, m, n;
    int res = 0;
    int **Tabuleiro;
    int cont = 0;
    int iteracoes = 0;

    do{
        do{
            printf("Dimensoes do ambiente\nLines\n");
            scanf("%d", &tab.N_Linhas);
        } while (tab.N_Linhas < 4 || tab.N_Linhas > 8);
        do{
            printf("Columns\n");
            scanf("%d", &tab.N_Colunas);
        } while (tab.N_Colunas < 6 || tab.N_Colunas > 10);
    } while (tab.N_Linhas > tab.N_Colunas);

    Tabuleiro = criaTabuleiro(tab.N_Linhas, tab.N_Colunas);

    GuardaFicheiro(tab.N_Linhas, tab.N_Colunas, Tabuleiro);
    //mostraTabuleiro(tab.N_Linhas, tab.N_Colunas, Tabuleiro, fnovo);
}
```

And, may be `main` like:

```
int main(){
    iniciaJogo();
    return 0;
}
```

I am sure the above code would work for you. But you should read little about C Programming - [functions](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson4.html), [structures](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson7.html), and [FileIO](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html).

There are many **unused variables** in your code, you may check compiling  your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra yourFileName.c`

Comment: i think it will work but i can't put mostraTabuleiro(6, 8, fnovo); cause 6 and 8 its the lines and columns and the player is the one that chooses. they are not fixed.

Comment: but i do... so i made a struct `struct tabuleiro{

 int N_Linhas;
 int N_Colunas;
};

typedef struct tabuleiro tabuleiro;` and i have to use it.

Comment: i will edit my question so i can show more code, okay?

Comment: Thank you so much, for helping me, and sorry cause i knew that it was a little bit frustrating. but i am pretty new to C and i have what i think is a big project for me. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

This should be corrected

```
fnovo = fopen(novo_fich, "wt");
```

into:

```
fnovo = fopen(novo_fich, "w");
```

after that use fprintf();

```
fprintf(fnovo, /*source char * */);
```